# Magento plugins Disable/enable problems

Tags: magento-1.9, php, amazon-web-services, caching

I am noticing really weird problems after installing plugins.

Sometimes the plugins get disappeared in the backend when we refresh the backend and sometimes it appears in the backend.

I havent used magento connect for installing the plugins.

Can this be a caching problems, even though we are using aws for hosting, we have redis cache.

Also after this whatever plugins we installed also has the configuration in the frontend, So once it has disappeared in the backend, this thing also gets disappeared in the frontend as well.

This problem is really gettting more weird and losing conversion very drastically.

Please someone let me know what can be the issue?

Below is the architecture list we are using at our end.

[image]

Comment: Please list your architecture.

Comment: Hi benmarks, i have added the list of architecture, and currently we are using redis cache.r3.large